# Create <dsp:input> element dynamically by jquery (ATG)

Tags: jquery, ajax, input, atg

I'm trying toadd "DSP:input" element to a "dsp:form" after page loaded, using jquery.
(I want to set some extra parameters according to the user behavior)

Since DSP input tags add some hidden fields, I cannot append from jquery like usual  tags.
Also I cannot generate them using Ajax since It doesn't allows to generate it without a surrounded  element.

Please help.

Thanks, Buddhika

Comment: `<dsp:>` tags are integrated in the page at page compile time. You cannot add them via JQuery. What you can do is have a separate form with all the `<dsp:input>` tags that you may require and then, with JQuery, populate these from the `HTML` form that you present to the customer. You then submit the 'hidden' form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Or rather, you can, but it will not have the effect you want.

DSP tags are interpreted on the server at request-processing time. DSP tags never make their way to the browser. The dsp:input tag in the JSP gets translated to a standard HTML input tag by the JSP processor.

By using JQuery to insert a DSP tag into your document, you are doing this on the client, in the browser. This DSP tag will not get processed by the server. And the browser knows nothing about how to render a DSP tag (because it is not HTML).

DSP tags are processed o the server prior to sending out the response to the browser. What you could do, if it makes sense, is render the dsp:input you want in your JSP first, and then use JQuery to remove the corresponding input tag from the HTML form in the situations where you do not need that input.